# Finding the direct object in a string or sentence using c#

Tags: c#, string, grammar

Is there a way or perhaps a library to find the direct object in a sentence?

For instance, given the sentence:

```
Jack scored a touchdown.
```

Touchdown is the direct object. Or another example.

```
I dislike vegetables.
```

Vegetables is the direct object.

Now one way to do this would be find the particular verb then pick the next word, but of course this won't always be accurate as the next word could be an adjective, a preposition etc..

So is there any particular way to programmatically finding the direct object in a sentence? Or perhaps even the indirect object?

Comment: See the SharpNLP project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12109/Statistical-parsing-of-English-sentences

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for speech recognition in msdn that allows you to create grammars and rules

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361659.aspx

Maybe you'll find what you need there, i have never used that part but speech recognition works nicely, i will assume the grammar creation and rule system is as such.

good luck